# PHP object scope Call to a member function on null

Tags: php, oop

i have a class called Users.php .Inside of this class i create a local variable like this:

```
class Users
{
    public $dbHelper;
}
```

inside of the Users class is a function called init inside of this function i set the $dbHelper variable to be a object of the DatabaseHelper.php class i wrote:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
}
```

now i try to call a method inside of the DatabaseHelper class like this:

```
public function login() 
{
    $this->dbHelper->executeSQLCommandWR(// HERE COMES THE QUERY STRING //);
}
```

But currently its giving me this error:

> Call to a member function executeSQLCommandWR() on null.

Why is the dbHelper variable null? In other oop programming langauages this works why not in this case?

Thanks for any help

Edit:

Im sorry i couldnt post all the code for this question because i was kind of in a rush when i created this question.

I call the init method as soon as my page gets loaded. It really seems like a scope problem i will try some of the answers and try to solve this problem. Thanks for everyone trying to help

Comment: Showing parts of code doesn't show full picture.

Comment: You call `init` before `login`? Maybe you want `__construct` instead?

Comment: Where do you call either of these functions?  The error seems to imply that you're doing so in the wrong order, or not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not called the init, but `init` is not a good practice if you call it right after the instantiate. You can put it into the constructor, but that wont be a clean code too.

Instead of this use:

```
public function login() {
  if (empty($this->dbHelper)) {
      $this->dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
  }
  $this->dbHelper->executeSQLCommandWR(// HERE COMES THE QUERY STRING //);
}
```

or

```
public function login() {
  $this->init();
  $this->dbHelper->executeSQLCommandWR(// HERE COMES THE QUERY STRING //);
}

public function init() {
  if (empty($this->dbHelper)) {
      $this->dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
  }
}
```

Second is better because of single responsible principle IMHO.

Comment: @PeterMader thx, fixed

Comment: Hey @vaso123, i call the init method as soon as my page gets loaded. Sorry i should have mentioned it in the first place. I will try your first suggestion and see if it works. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Then you need to check the credentials. Maybe database connection was not success. Try `var_dump($this->dbHelper);` after `init`.

Comment: i tried your first solution and it worked. I guess is stick with this way thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have not initialized the member variable $dbHelper,
you haven't provided it with any value, therefore, it's null.

Comment: When i do this: $this->dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(); The dbHelper is a object of the DatabaseHelper class or am i wrong?

Comment: you are not wrong from OOP point of view but php is only adopting OOP. So php would expect you to create your objects outside of class

Answer (score -1):

```
public function login() 
{
$this->init();
$this->dbHelper->executeSQLCommandWR(// HERE COMES THE QUERY STRING //);
}
```

It seems to be a variable scope problem call the function init in the login function to define the variable

Comment: this works and i already tried it. The problem is i didnt want to define the variable every time the login method is called. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Try to define it as Const dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(); it will be access from all class methods